# RealVNC Logging on Windows

Tags: windows, logging, realvnc

I'd like to see who WAS connected using RealVNC to a specific machine, running Windows 2008 server R2 64bit.

Is it in the event viewer? Where exactly?

Is logging turned on by default?

Answer (score 0):

The RealVNC server in service mode does log to the EventLog by default.

To see the log open Event viewer then expand the "Windows Logs" group, then select the Application log.

Details of who was connected and from which IP address are logged as part of the default logging.

There is more about logging here: https://www.realvnc.com/docs/logging.html#all-about-logging